# SQL Server combining 2 rows into 1 from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with an JobID (PK), EmployeeID (FK), StartDate, EndDate containing data such as:

```
1, 10, '01-Jan-2010 08:00:00', '01-Jan-2010 08:30:00'
2, 10, '01-Jan-2010 08:50:00', '01-Jan-2010 09:05:00'
3, 10, '02-Feb-2010 10:00:00', '02-Feb-2010 10:30:00'
```

I want to return a record for each EndDate for a Job and then the same employees StartDate for his next immediate job (by date time). So from the data above the result would be

```
Result 1: 10, 01-Jan-2010 08:30:00, 01-Jan-2010 08:50:00
Result 2: 10, 01-Jan-2010 09:05:00, 02-Feb-2010 10:00:00
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Can EndDate in a row be after the StartDate in a subsequent row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lance's code has a problem. Here is the corrected query that will work:

```
select j1.JobID, j1.EmployeeID, j1.EndDate, 
(
    select top 1 j2.StartDate 
      from Job j2
     where j2.EmployeeID = j1.EmployeeID
       and j2.StartDate > j1.EndDate
     order by j2.StartDate
) as NextStartDate
from Job j1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be one way:

```
select j1.JobID, j1.EmployeeID, j1.EndDate, 
(
    select top 1 j2.StartDate from Job j2
    where j2.EmployeeID = j1.EmployeeID
    order by j2.StartDate
    where j2.StartDate > j1.EndDate
) as NextStartDate
from Job j1
```

Good luck!